# How to check if certain variables and specific keys of a dictionary are None in a pythonic way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Assuming a `dict` as follows:

```
dict_a = {'cc':None, 'pt':None, 'v':87.7, 'sd':None}
```

and a couple of variables (which aren't a part of the dictionary) as follows:

```
vf = None
vt = None
```

What I would like to do is to do a check if `cc`, `pt`, `vf`, `vt` are `None` all at once.

I have tried:

```
if all(dict_a[c] is None for c in ('cc', 'pt')):
    if all(i is None for i in (vf, vt)):
        print('Values are none')
```

and it works, but is there a more efficient and more pythonic way of checking if the keys in the `dict` and the variables are none?

Comment: can it be that the variables (in this case `vf` and `vt`) are also dict keys?

Comment: @Ma0 No. They are not a part of dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit skeptical about this one. Your code seems just fine and the distinction between dict values and variables being `None` feels reasonable. However, there is this you could try:

```
all(dict_a.get(x, x) is None for x in ('cc', 'pt', vf, vt))
```

...but you need to be a bit more careful with it.

---

One (rather convoluted) example of it going bad would be having a `None` key in the initial dictionary pointing to a non-`None` value and both of the `vf`, `vt` being `None` at the same time. That would produce a false negative.

---

A more robust and elegant alternative would be:

```
all(globals().get(x, dict_a.get(x, '')) is None for x in ('cc', 'pt', 'vf', 'vt'))
```

but here you have to quote the `'vf'` & `'vt'`

Comment: Thanks for this :) I will be careful while using this